# Cron job is not executing in google app engine + Laravel 4

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4, cron

I am shifting my application developed in Laravel 4 to Google App Engine. I have followed steps mentioned in this tutorial

https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/10/22/getting-started-with-laravel-on-php-for-app-engine/

Everything went perfect. To setup cron jb in Google App engine I created a cron.yaml file. But the problem is it is not getting executed. I have searched for solutions but found nothing on this. Following is my cron.yaml file

```
cron:
 - description: Todo reminder
   url: /gae_cron/todo_reminder
   schedule: every 1 minutes from 00:00 to 23:59
```

My app.yaml file

```
application: test
version: beta-1-11
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:

    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: public/favicon.ico
      upload: public/favicon\.ico

    - url: /packages
      static_dir: public/packages

    - url: /assets
      static_dir: public/assets

    - url: /views
      static_dir: public/views

    - url: /.*
      script: public/index.php
```

Here is the route that I am calling from cron.yaml

```
 Route::get('gae_cron/todo_reminder', function() {
   Log::info('todo reminder route');
 });
```

But I can't see anything in the log. However when I execute it by directly pasting url in the browser it is showing in the log.

Has anyone managed to make cron job work in GAE with Laravel.

Comment: Do you see the cron job in the developer console (`Compute`->`App Engine`->`Task queues` on the left menu then `Cron Jobs` tab)?

Comment: @DanCornilescu It is not showing anything there

Comment: See if this answer (applied to PHP) helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32206102/python-google-app-engine-cron-job-not-working/32206692#32206692

Comment: @DanCornilescu tried but getting this error appcfg.py: error: Expected a <directory> argument after 'update_cron'.

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks for pointing me to this direction, finally it worked. GAE doc says it uploads cron.yaml when we deploy the application, but in my case it worked when i uploaded it separately with appcfg.py -A <project-id> update_cron .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Google App Engine Document

```
You can use appcfg.py to upload cron jobs and view information about the defined cron jobs. When you upload your application to App Engine using appcfg.py update, the Cron Service is updated with the contents of cron.yaml. You can update just the cron configuration without uploading the rest of the application using appcfg.py update_cron
```

To upload cron entries separately

```
appcfg.py -A <project-id> update_cron .
```

To verify goto

```
Compute->App Engine->Task queues
```

There you will find all the cron entries that you had mentioned in the cron.yaml file